# How to add custom beans globally to spring boot test context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, junit5

I implemented firebase messaging into my spring boot application. For that I created a bean like described [here](https://springhow.com/spring-boot-firebase-push-notification/#java-configuration-for-messaging) for easy access to a `FirebaseMessaging` instance. That bean then is injected into a service. Said service is then injected into my controller were the service methods that utilize the `FirebaseMessaging` bean are called.

Now my problem is that the testsuite for that project (using JUnit5 & TestContainers) fails as the following stacktrace is thrown for each method:

```
MyControllerTest > testFunction() FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException at ConstructorResolver.java:800
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at ConstructorResolver.java:658
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException at ConstructorResolver.java:800
                Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException at SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at ConstructorResolver.java:658
                Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException at SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185
                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException at Preconditions.java:513
                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException at Preconditions.java:513
```

Root Cause:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp name my-app already exists!
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:513)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:222)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:215)
    at my.example.app.firebase.FirebaseMessagingBean.firebaseMessaging(FirebaseMessagingBean.kt:25)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 125 more
```

*Note: The errors only occour when running the testsuite as a whole. If I run a test class on it's own no error appears.*

On method to solve that problem is to add a `@MockBean` to each class so the test context is loading the bean. So with that I could go on and simply add that to each test class, but I would prefer a method that injects a `FirebaseMessaging` `@MockBean` into each test class automatically the testsuite don't fails each time a dev forgets to add the `@MockBean` to his test class.

What is a proper way to achieve that?

*(This code is in Kotlin, but I'ld also happily accept java code for the solution.)*

*Code:*

```kotlin
@Component
class FirebaseMessagingBean {
    @Bean
    fun firebaseMessaging(): FirebaseMessaging {
        val privateKeyFileURL = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("firebase-cloud-messaging.json")
            ?: throw IOException("Couldn't read firebase credentials")
        val privateKeyStream = File(privateKeyFileURL.file).inputStream()
        val googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(privateKeyStream)
        val firebaseOptions = FirebaseOptions.builder().setCredentials(googleCredentials)
            .build()
        val app = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(firebaseOptions, "my-app")
        return FirebaseMessaging.getInstance(app)
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@Service
class FirebaseNotificationService(
    val firebaseMessaging: FirebaseMessaging
) {
    fun sendNotification(msg: String) { /* ... */ }
}
```

```kotlin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/route")
class MyController(
    val firebaseNotificationService: FirebaseNotificationService,
) {
    @PostMapping()
    fun postRoute(): ResponseEntity<Any> {
        firebaseNotificationService.sendNotification("msg")
        // ...
    }
}
```

Test class example

```kotlin
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest
class DeviceControllerTest {
    // injections
    
    @Test
    fun testFunction() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a more detailed stack trace, e.g. the message? Do you use `@SpringBootTest` or how is your test set up? Seeing your test code or an excerpt of the relevant parts would be helpful.

Comment: I've added some more code/stacktrace that hopefully clarifies it a bit.

Comment: Thanks for providing more details. Even though you already found a solution to your problem, I've taken the liberty to  add a slightly different approach for others who might stumble upon the same situation. Or maybe you're interested yourself aswell.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem by only initiliazing the `FirebaseApp` instance when there wasn't one instantiated before.

The updated bean:

```kotlin
class FirebaseMessagingBean {
    @Bean
    fun firebaseMessaging(): FirebaseMessaging {
        val privateKeyFileURL = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("firebase-cloud-messaging.json")
            ?: throw IOException("Couldn't read firebase credentials")
        val privateKeyStream = File(privateKeyFileURL.file).inputStream()
        val googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(privateKeyStream)
        val firebaseOptions = FirebaseOptions
            .builder()
            .setCredentials(googleCredentials)
            .build()
        val app = try {
            FirebaseApp.getInstance()
        } catch (iae: IllegalStateException) {
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(firebaseOptions)
        }
        return FirebaseMessaging.getInstance(app)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem originates from the fact, that Firebase uses a `FirebaseApp` object as static singleton factory, which disallows to be called more than once for the same app. When running a single test this is not a problem, because the call is only issued once. When running multiple test suites however, the wrapping Bean is created anew for every ApplicationContext but the `FirebaseApp` object is kept for the runtime of the JVM and NOT re-created. Because `initializeApp` is invoked multiple times for the same app on the same `FirebaseApp` object, the error shown above is yielded.

One way to solve this, is by catching the exception thrown by the factory, as shown in your answer.
However, you could also take advantage of Kotlin features to solve this issue, without creating a costly `Exception` for every test.

```kotlin
private val firebaseMessaging: FirebaseMessaging by lazy {
    val privateKeyFileURL = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("firebase-cloud-messaging.json")
        ?: throw IOException("Couldn't read firebase credentials")
    val privateKeyStream = File(privateKeyFileURL.file).inputStream()
    val googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(privateKeyStream)
    val firebaseOptions = FirebaseOptions.builder().setCredentials(googleCredentials)
        .build()
    val app = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(firebaseOptions, "my-app")

    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance(app)
}

@Component
class FirebaseMessagingBean {

    @Bean
    fun firebaseMessaging(): FirebaseMessaging = firebaseMessaging
}
```

By utilizing the `lazy` delegate, the initialization is called once only, and only when first required.

Comment: That seems like a much better approach - at least for kotlin users. Will give it a try and let you know it solves my problem as well!

Comment: I hope it does, I did not set up a project with Firebase myself, thus I could not test it. Let me know if something does not work. :-)